# com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: The requested metadata is not found in github actions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-dynamodb, github-actions

I have a simple program that only tries to query a dynamo db table in order to bring elements in Java. When I run it locally with maven or with the IDE it works fine, but when I try to do it in a Github Actions workflow it throws the following stacktrace:

```
Jun 24, 2020 11:35:36 AM com.amazonaws.util.EC2MetadataUtils getItems
11429
WARNING: Unable to retrieve the requested metadata (/latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document). The requested metadata is not found at http://169.254.169.254/latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document
11430
com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: The requested metadata is not found at http://169.254.169.254/latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document
11431
    at com.amazonaws.internal.EC2CredentialsUtils.readResource(EC2CredentialsUtils.java:122)
11432
    at com.amazonaws.internal.EC2CredentialsUtils.readResource(EC2CredentialsUtils.java:82)
11433
    at com.amazonaws.util.EC2MetadataUtils.getItems(EC2MetadataUtils.java:400)
11434
    at com.amazonaws.util.EC2MetadataUtils.getData(EC2MetadataUtils.java:369)
11435
    at com.amazonaws.util.EC2MetadataUtils.getData(EC2MetadataUtils.java:365)
11436
    at com.amazonaws.util.EC2MetadataUtils.getEC2InstanceRegion(EC2MetadataUtils.java:280)
11437
    at com.amazonaws.regions.InstanceMetadataRegionProvider.tryDetectRegion(InstanceMetadataRegionProvider.java:59)
    at com.amazonaws.regions.InstanceMetadataRegionProvider.getRegion(InstanceMetadataRegionProvider.java:50)
11439
    at com.amazonaws.regions.AwsRegionProviderChain.getRegion(AwsRegionProviderChain.java:46)
11440
    at com.amazonaws.client.builder.AwsClientBuilder.determineRegionFromRegionProvider(AwsClientBuilder.java:475)
11441
    at com.amazonaws.client.builder.AwsClientBuilder.setRegion(AwsClientBuilder.java:458)
11442
    at com.amazonaws.client.builder.AwsClientBuilder.configureMutableProperties(AwsClientBuilder.java:424)
11443
    at com.amazonaws.client.builder.AwsSyncClientBuilder.build(AwsSyncClientBuilder.java:46)
11444
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.defaultClient(AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.java:53)
11445
    at com.services.dynamo.DynamoDBConfiguration.<clinit>(DynamoDBConfiguration.java:17)
11446
    at com.services.dynamo.BaseDynamoDBRepository.<init>(BaseDynamoDBRepository.java:95)
11447
    at com.services.dynamo.BaseDynamoDBRepository.<init>(BaseDynamoDBRepository.java:31)
11448
    at com.services.dynamo.ManagerImpl.<init>(RepositoryImpl.java:48)
11449
    at com.services.dynamo.Manager.<init>(ManagerImpl.java:22)
11450
    at com.bancar.services.MyClass.testing(AssociateLineOfCreditAndApproveLoanTest.java:71)
11451
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
11452
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
11453
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
11454
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
11455
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
11456
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
11457
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
11458
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
11459
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
11460
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
11461
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
11462
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
11462
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
11463
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
11464
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
11465
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
11466
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
11467
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
11468
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
11469
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
11470
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
11471
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.run(JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.java:37)
11472
    at org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:62)
11473
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:236)
11474
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:134)
11475
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:113)
11476
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
11477
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
11478
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
11479
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
11480
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
11481
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
11482
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
11483
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:103)
11484
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:74)
```

I'm not using any instance of EC2 (maybe aws does it). The code is a bit complex to show because is a whole library, but basically it doesn't create the dynamo db client.

The line specified in the stacktrace which throws an error that belongs to my code is when I initialize the instance:

```
AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.defaultClient()
```

I thing I may configure something else in the workflow, but I can't find what.

Any ideas of what might be wrong?

Comment: You are trying to access instance metadata (http://169.254.169.254/latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document) which is only available for EC2 instances.

Comment: I'm not intentionally trying to access there, dynamo does it by itself? Why is running correctly in my local environment and even in jenkins, but with github actions fails?

Comment: Don't know. Maybe it tries to find some AWS credentials, but it can't, thus it tries to get them through instance metadata. On you local environment maybe there is no such problem?

Comment: It seems it tries to get region from metadata: `getRegion(InstanceMetadataRegionProvider)`

Comment: I'm trying to use local dynamodb, so I configure mocked credentials and the setup works fine with that. In my computer works well running the same command, and I'm not running any instance. I also tried using the real credentials just to see if it works, but same error,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution when I say the aws documentation which has this set int the method that fails:

```
        // Note: This is a bug in the provider chain. The chain should return null when no region is found according to
        // the interface, but an exception is thrown  here instead. This class is used in too many places to change now.
        // TODO: In 2.0, be sure this bug does not carry through.
        throw new SdkClientException("Unable to load region information from any provider in the chain");
```

I managed to fix it adding the following step to the workflow:

```
      - name: Configure AWS Credentials
        uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
        with:
          aws-access-key-id: {realAccessKey}
          aws-secret-access-key: {realSecretAccessKey}
          aws-region: {region}
```

Even if you use local dynamodb, you should provide real credentials, doesn't matter if the tables don't exist in that account, then it will try to access locally and the job will work fine.